# SchedulerFactory instantiates different scheduled jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have two different quartz schedulers. The first one is a Cron Scheduler that and the second one is a Simple Scheduler. 
The Cron one starts when my servlet is instantiated (init() method) while the second one must start at a specific time.

The problem is that the first scheduler triggers the second one.

```
public static void startScheduleJobForDBCheck() throws SchedulerException {
        log.info("Schedule will start for checking database at the start of each day");
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(View.class)
                .withIdentity("view")
                .build();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        ScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = 
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 05 0-1 ? * 1-7");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().
                withSchedule(scheduleBuilder).build();

        SchedulerFactory CronchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler CronScheduler = CronchedulerFactory.getScheduler();

        CronScheduler.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
        CronScheduler.start();
     }

 public static void startScheduleJobForInitialization(int hour,int day,int duration) throws SchedulerException, InterruptedException {
        log.info("Schedule will execute the thread at " + hour + " o'clock");

        SchedulerFactory SimpleschedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler simpleScheduler = SimpleschedulerFactory.getScheduler();

            JobDetail simpleJob = JobBuilder.newJob(WateringScheduler.class)
                    .withIdentity("insert")
                    .build();

            simpleJob.getJobDataMap().put("hour", duration);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = new Calendar.Builder()
                    .setDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), day)
                    .setTimeOfDay(hour, 13, 0)
                    .build().getTime();

            log.info("Starting date at :" + date);

            SimpleTrigger simpletrigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("TriggerOnce", "group1")
                .startAt(date)
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                .withIntervalInSeconds(duration)
                .withRepeatCount(0)).build();

            simpleScheduler.start();
            simpleScheduler.scheduleJob(simpleJob, simpletrigger);
 }
```

Shouldn't the new StdSchedulerFactory() instantiate a new object?